# How to safely call disconnect in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I am using qt 4.8.
And I write something like:

```
Myclass* A = input_class_pointer;
... 
disconnect(A,SIGNAL(A_S()),B,SLOT(B_S()));
```

However, sometimes when I call this, I found that the actual instance of A is already deleted somewhere else. And now the pointer A is pointing into rubbish. And by calling the disconnect, it resulted a crash.
Is there any simple way to solve this which require minimum amount of modification in the code?
I have many similar issues...

Comment: Well...if you delete `A` yourself you should set the pointer to 0 so you could easily check it before calling disconnect. If Qt deletes it for you then you do not have to disconnect it at all. If both cases may occur you probably have to rethink your architecture

Comment: I did not delete A.but delete the input_class_pointer somewhere outside the function. When the code reaches the line disconnect, though A != Null, its pointing to nothing...

Comment: @Nyaruko Could smart pointers be a solution? Smart pointers usually have this `isEmpty` member function which could be useful.

Comment: This might be a job for the QPointer class -- a QPointer will "magically" become a NULL pointer when the object it points to is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments above there ways to detect whether the instance of QObject was deleted or not. One is QPointer which is a type of weak-pointer. But the problem is that we want to know when that QObject gets deleted, not after the fact. So, there is [QObject::destroyed](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#destroyed) signal for that.

```
connect(A, destroyed(QObject*), this, onWatchObjDestroyed(QObject*));
```

And in your class code that watches some objects:

```
void MyClass::onWatchObjDestroyed(QObject* pObj)
{
   // do certain disconnects for pObj, etc. if needed (?)
}
```